# What does the left control key on a Mac map to in Debian?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard

I'd like to use the left control key on my mac as the compose key in Debian, but I can't figure out what its equivalent is in the installation menu.  My best guess is that left control on a Mac maps to the "left flag" key. What key does it really map to?

Comment: Open terminal, type in XEV. Hit the key, and look at the terminal output.

Comment: @ROB - what environment do I need to be in to execute XEV?  It isn't found in /bin/sh in the Ububtu 11.04 installer environment.

Comment: Flag it ubuntu instead of debian. try sudo apt-get install xev